# How do I insert a BC date into Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Just wondering how I would insert the date 01/01/4000BC into oracle

Have tried the following but to no avail

```
INSERT INTO person(birth_date) VALUES(TO_DATE('-4700/01/01', 'syyyy/mm/dd'))
```

I'm sure I've missed something pretty obvious so some fresh eyes on this would really help.

Thanks!

Comment: the WHERE... doesn't belong into an INSERT...

Comment: I suspect your insert is working correctly, but when you are viewing the date you're using a date format (probably the default) that doesn't include the BC indicator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see the problem with your syntax. It works for me:

```
Connected to Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 
Connected as xxx

SQL> CREATE TABLE tt (d DATE);

Table created

SQL> INSERT INTO tt VALUES (to_date('-4700/01/01','syyyy/mm/dd'));

1 row inserted

SQL> SELECT to_char(d, 'MM/DD/YYYY BC') FROM tt;

TO_CHAR(D,'MM/DD/YYYYBC')
-------------------------
01/01/4700 BC

SQL>
```

What is the exact issue you're having? What version of Oracle?

You do have to use the BC or SYYYY format specifier on output else you get incorrect dates:

```
SQL> select * from tt;

D
-----------
00-h:mm:ss

SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO person(birth_date)
 VALUES(TO_DATE('4000/01/01 BC', 'yyyy/mm/dd bc'))
```

Comment: @Ricardo: No it doesn't I have tested it.

Comment: Ok. I'll remove the comment. But I've tested it too and got that error. Copied your statement and pasted it changing only the table and column names. Actually, the error message is different: `SQL Error: ORA-01856: BC/B.C. or AD/A.D. required
01856. 00000 -  "BC/B.C. or AD/A.D. required"`

Comment: OK, it's probably a localization issue?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
INSERT INTO person(birth_date) VALUES(TO_DATE('-4700/01/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd'))
```

or you could use BC notation - see http://rwijk.blogspot.com/2008/10/year-zero.html

Comment: this statement will return an error: `SQL Error: ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0`. you should use the format picture as `'syyyy/mm/dd'`