# Inserting a B.C. year value from a flat file to Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, date, sql-loader

I am using `sqlldr` to transfer data from a flat file (.txt) to oracle db. As for dates I am using `"to_date(:born, 'DDMMYY')"`, where `born` is the column. How can I specify a B.C. year (e.x: 01-01-1000BC) in my flat file so that it can be transfered to my oracle table?

Comment: BC is just a negative year with a change to your string format  Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779521/how-do-i-insert-a-bc-date-into-oracle  or `to_date('-1000/01/01','syyyy/mm/dd')`

Comment: Yes, I have read that, but how do I specify it in my .txt file? I am inputing the date in the text file and then it is transfered by sqlldr to db table. I am specifying the date like: 01011990, for 01-01-1990. What should I write for the B.C. value?

Comment: How about load it as a varchar(20) and then after import run the to_date on it adding a new field then drop original field?  I'd have to research the sqlldr more to know if there's a way to handle the BC in a single step; can the date be -10000101 SYYYYMMDD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make the string in the text file always have a BC or AD suffix (you can't omit AD in this scenario), e.g. `01011000BC` and `01011990AD`, and then in your control file:

```
"to_date(:born, 'DDMMYYYYBC')"
```

Or you can do the same thing with the sign option if you only want to change negative values, e.g. `0101-1000` and `19900101` and then in the control file:

```
"to_date(:born, 'DDMMSYYYY')"
```

which looks rather odd for the BC value.

Since you seem to control the format, it would be simpler and more readable to put the elements in YYYYMMDD order, e.g. `-10001231` and `19901231` (changing the dates to help distinguish between months and days in the string) and then:

```
"to_date(:born, 'SYYYYMMDD')"
```

which is essentially what @xQbert suggested.